# DTS xml transform/manipulate using Ruby REXML

Tags: .net, sql, ruby, ssis, rake

I am working on a DTS SSIS package and aiming to use Teamcity buildserver (via Ruby / rake)... basically I want to customise for each environment (Dev, UAT, Prod) with different connection strings..

for example in Test I want to point to SQL2008Test, and in Dev SQL2008Dev. That means I'll need to manipulate my dts package before its being deployed to the respective directory....

anyone got good experience with REXML - ruby?

This is my ruby code (with a rakefile)

```
config = {}
File.open(File.join(BUILD_SSIS_DIR, IRS_DSS_USER_PACKAGE)) do |config_file|
    config = REXML::Document.new(config_file)
ConfigTasks.set_dts_constring_irs config, 'ConnectionString', 
"Data Source=SQL2008DEV;Initial Catalog=IRSDEV;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-IRS DSS User Data Package-{3CC00FAB-7009-402D-AE03-2426AFC6B7ED}SQL2008 IRS Multiple Connection;"
end
```

and it calls

```
def self.set_dts_constring_irs(config_file, name, connection_string)
    conn_string_element = config_file.root.elements['DTS:ConnectionManager/DTS:Property'];
    conn_string_element['DTS:Name="ConnectionString"'] = connection_string
end
```

this is my DTS xml that I need to manipulate

```
  <DTS:ConnectionManager>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DelayValidation">0</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">SQL2008 IRS Multiple Connection</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{3CC00FAB-7009-402D-AE03-2426AFC6B7ED}</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description"></DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName">OLEDB</DTS:Property><DTS:ObjectData><DTS:ConnectionManager>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Retain">0</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConnectionString">Data Source=SQL2008DEV;Initial Catalog=IRSDEV;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-IRS DSS User Data Package-{3CC00FAB-7009-402D-AE03-2426AFC6B7ED}SQL2008 IRS Multiple Connection;</DTS:Property>
</DTS:ConnectionManager></DTS:ObjectData>
</DTS:ConnectionManager>
```

anyone got thoughts in terms of my work? e.g. how to use REXML to drill down the elements / attributes of connectionstring I need??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to use REXML to find the connection string in an XML file, and to replace it with your own connection string. REXML lets you use XPath to find an element and to set it's value:

```
require 'rexml/document'

# assuming:
xml = '<DTS xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts">
         <DTS:ConnectionManager>
           <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DelayValidation">0</DTS:Property>
           <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">SQL2008 IRS Multiple Connection</DTS:Property>
           <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{3CC00FAB-7009-402D-AE03-2426AFC6B7ED</DTS:Property>
           <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description"></DTS:Property>
           <DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName">OLEDB</DTS:Property>
           <DTS:ObjectData>
             <DTS:ConnectionManager>
               <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Retain">0</DTS:Property>
               <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConnectionString">Data Source=SQL2008DEV;Initial Catalog=IRSDEV;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-IRS DSS User Data Package-{3CC00FAB-7009-402D-AE03-2426AFC6B7ED}SQL2008 IRS Multiple Connection;</DTS:Property>
            </DTS:ConnectionManager>
           </DTS:ObjectData>
         </DTS:ConnectionManager>
       </DTS>'

# find the connection string with XPath
connection_string_xpath = '/DTS/DTS:ConnectionManager/DTS:ObjectData/DTS:ConnectionManager/DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="ConnectionString"]'
new_connection_string = 'your new connection string here'

begin
  doc = REXML::Document.new(xml)
  root = doc.root
  # check that you can find the path you are looking for
  unless root.elements[connection_string_xpath].nil?
    # set the .text of the element to your connection string:
    root.elements[connection_string_xpath].text = new_connection_string
    # test:
    puts doc
  end
rescue REXML::ParseException => rexml_exception
  puts 'Invalid XML', rexml_exception
end
```

which will output (some XML removed ...):

```
...
<DTS:Property DTS:Name='ConnectionString'>your new connection string here</DTS:Property>
...
```

Comment: you're awesome dude... nice. I'll do some tweaking regarding this... so now the XPATH bit makes lots of sense!